# SVG animateTransform does not start

Tags: javascript, svg, webkit, svg-animate

I was writing a piece of SVG code and ran into the following issue:

The animateTransform tag won't work (cannot start the animation) if the SVG isn't appended to the document with the window onload event.

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/r4WEh/
vs
http://jsfiddle.net/r4WEh/1/

The only difference being:

```
init();
```

vs

```
window.onclick = init;
```

In the first one the svg is added to the dom with the window onload event.
In the second one the svg is added to the dom on a mouseclick event.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly on Firefox. If you're using Safari or Chrome you're probably suffering from [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74801)

Comment: It does seem to be the issue. Thanks a lot guys